# How to dynamically load js file in master page based on aspx page loaded?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, master-page, custom-masterpage

I have include all the link to my javascript file in my master page using  tag. Can I load specific js file according to pages loaded? (for example, I would like to load home.js only when Home.aspx is loaded).

Comment: Can't you just put the reference to home.js in the header of the home.aspx? So it will be loaded only when you navigate to Home.aspx. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: As above (Norbert). Or use dynamic names of your files that match for instance home.aspx loads home.js with a document.url parse.

Answer (score 0):

create an event handler that runs on page load! this can be added to a feature to turn off and on!

within the event handler you can add:

```
    private string BindScript(string ScriptUrl, bool PickFromSiteCollection)
    {
        if (PickFromSiteCollection)
            ScriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url, ScriptUrl);
        else
            ScriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, ScriptUrl);
        return string.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""{0}""></script>", ScriptUrl);
    }
```

you can call the above method on the page load event! do it like so:

```
writer.Write(BindScript("/_layouts/1033/js/jquery.min.js", true));
```

so when you first add the wsp you can activate the feature, the feature will run on each page load event. obviously you need to have a case statment or if function to check what page its on! if its on a specific page you can then bind the JS to the masterpage!